# splitting pandas dataframe - np.array_split error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split dataframe, this code used to work just fine:

```
split_dfs = np.array_split(big_df,8)
```

now it gives me error (i did a system update in between):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prepare_fixations_dataset.py", line 127, in <module>
    split_dfs = np.array_split(big_df,8)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 426, in array_split
    if sub_arys[-1].size == 0 and sub_arys[-1].ndim != 1:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.15.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1936, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'size'
```

if you have any siggestions why it may not work now please let me know.

Comment: Well, answer your question and accept your answer.

Comment: Or delete the question. In any case, don't edit the title to include "Solved": Stackoverflow doesn't adhere to that practice.

Comment: I really think that your comments miss the point and don't know why I should delete a question that might be helpful to someone also affected by this pandas/numpy bug. If you have a good reason why I should delete, I'd be glad to hear it. I'm deleting "solved".

Comment: I'm guessing there was some kind of answer in the comments but clearly that has disappeared.  If this no longer needs answering you should either delete the question or answer it and accept your own answer.

Comment: @yemu It can be useful to other persons indeed, but for that you have to answer your question and accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is caused by the bug in numpy 1.9.0 or regression and incompatibility between numpy 1.9.0 and pandas 0.15.1.this bug doesn't happen with numpy 1.8.1 and pandas 0.15.1.

i filed a bug in the pandas github:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8846

seems it is already fixed for pandas 0.15.2